# How to test exception for function which has return value in solidity?

Tags: solidity

I'm writing unit tests for my smart contract. And I want to cover exception testing. Following [this tutorial](https://www.trufflesuite.com/tutorials/testing-for-throws-in-solidity-tests), I could use a test proxy to test a function which doesn't return anything. However, I got error when testing function which has return value.

This is the contract to be tested:

```
pragma solidity >=0.5.0 <0.6.0;

contract ContractA {
    uint256 public count;

    constructor(uint256 init) public {
        count = init;
    }

    function add(uint256 val) public returns(uint256) {
        require(val > 0);
        count = count + val;

        return count;
    }
}
```

This is the test proxy:

```
pragma solidity >=0.5.0 <0.6.0;

contract TestProxy {
  address public target;
  bytes data;

  constructor(address _target) public {
    target = _target;
  }

  function() external payable {
    data = msg.data;
  }

  function execute() public returns (bool success, bytes memory response) {
    (success, response) = target.call(data);
  }
}
```

This is test contract:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.0 <0.6.0;
import "remix_tests.sol"; // this import is automatically injected by Remix.
import "./TestProxy.sol";
import "./ContractA.sol";

// file name has to end with '_test.sol'
contract TestContractA {
  function testAdd() public {
    ContractA conA = new ContractA(1);
    TestProxy tp = new TestProxy(address(conA));        
    ContractA(address(tp)).add(0);        
    (bool r,) = tp.execute.gas(20000)();
    Assert.equal(r, false, "the call should fail");
}
```

The test got this error:

```
Transaction has been reverted by the EVM: { "transactionHash": "0xb4603e0ba5dbc2d96511a38a01113c586252baccff1e3f7029ad7abc8994aecc", "transactionIndex": 0, "blockHash": "0x766d18646a06cf74faeabf38597314f84a82c3851859d9da9d94fc8d037269e5", "blockNumber": 6, "gasUsed": 406623, "cumulativeGasUsed": 406623, "status": false, "events": {} }
```

I'm wondering if this is a know issue or limitation in solidity or something I missed? I found a workaround. But if this is bug of solidity, it is better to be fixed.

Comment: Well first of all you have a syntax error where you did not close the `testAdd` contract's bracket. Also, your proxy has not configured a fallback function that points to your original contract that is why the EVM is reverting the transaction because it expects the contract to have the add function and it does not. Without a fallback function, you are supposed to call the execute function with the appropriate data.